# stuck with Preg_replace() to Preg_replace_callback()

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I am trying to convert this function to preg_replace_callback but almost everything that I tried gives error:

***Requires argument 2, '$db->module', to be a valid callback in***

This is my code:

```
$this->template = preg_replace ("/#module\=(\w+)#/ie", "\$this->module('\\1')", $this->template);
```

Any ideas how to convert it?..

Comment: a callback is a function, which parameters and return values should be carefully chosen with respect to http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: I will reopen the question since it is a particular case in which a class method needs to be used the callback function.

Answer (score 3):

I answer this question exceptionally because you have to use a class method in it. So it isn't so simple than the million of answers about the subject.

One way to do it, change the pattern in a way the whole match is the `yourclass::module` parameter and pass an array with `$this` and the method name as second parameter:

```
$this->template = preg_replace_callback('/#module=\K\w+(?=#)/i', array($this, 'module'), $this->template);
```

or

```
$this->template = preg_replace_callback('/#module=\K\w+(?=#)/i', 'self::module', $this->template);
```

Other way, keep the same pattern and use the `$that=$this;` trick:

```
$that = $this;
$this->template = preg_replace_callback('/#module=(\w+)#/i', function ($m) use ($that) {
    return $that->module($m[1]);
}, $this->template);
```